# IServiceCollection doesn't contain any elements when injected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**UPDATE - Fix**

> Added the services and directly injected them into the constructors.
>   Implemented service and application option registrations as extensions.

I have a tag helper that rely on *IServiceCollection* to be injected for requesting services, but the collection doesn't contain any elements even though I've registered two services in Startup.

The services gets registered in an asp.net core web application that references a class library which contains the tag helper, so it's two separate projects.

I also had to register *IServiceCollection* as a service since it fails without (missing service in the tag helper when trying to request IRazorViewEngine), but I thought the collection was automatically registered. It seems strange to add a collection to another collection of the same type..?

Everything is Core 2.0

Web application, **Startup.cs**:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}   

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IServiceCollection, ServiceCollection>();
    services.AddSingleton<IRazorViewEngine, RazorViewEngine>();

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseBrowserLink();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Main}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

Class library, **ViewResourceTagHelper.cs**:

```
private IHttpContextAccessor _http;
private IServiceCollection _services;

public ViewResourceTagHelper(IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceCollection services) : base(env)
{           
    using (ServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
    {
        _http = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    }

    _services = services;
}
```

Comment: Don't edit a 'fix' into the question. You can post a self-answer if that adds anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject a `IServiceProvider` instance rather than a `IServiceCollection` instance:

```
public ViewResourceTagHelper(IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider provider) : base(env)
{
    _http = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

Injecting a `IServiceCollection` makes no sense since it's used to *configure* the container. The `IServiceProvider` *is* the container which resolves services for you. The `ServiceCollection` instance which gets injected in empty because DI just news up a new and empty instance for you.

I wonder though, why do you not inject a `IHttpContextAccessor` instance directly? By the way, you have to register an instance for `IHttpContextAccessor` as well, as it's not registered by default:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Take a look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) for more information about Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: ah I see. every example I found used the collection. thank you!